# When two tiles meet, the edges that come together must be of the same colour.

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math, tiling

Each **1x1** tile has a red side opposite a yellow side,and a blue side opposite a green side.An **8x8** chessboard is formed from **64** of these tiles,which may be turned around or turned over.When two tiles meet,the edges that come together must be of the same color.How many different chessboards can be formed?
Turning the chessboard around or turning the chessboard over is not allowed.

Taken from CIMC 2015

Comment: What have you tried? The conditions are pretty restrictive, so a subset of the board might determine the entire board.

Comment: Hint: If the base of the a1 square is red, say, then the bases of the squares a2, a3,...,a8 must be yellow, red, yellow,...,yellow. Now look at the left-hand edges of these squares.

Answer (score 1):

Either all vertical edges are red or yellow and all horizontal edges blue or green, or vice versa. The colour of the horizontal edges must alternate in each column, and the colour of the vertical edges must alternate in each row. Because the tiles can be turned over, these alternations can all be chosen independently. Thus there are $8$ binary choices for the rows, $8$ binary choices for the columns and $1$ binary choice for the overall orientation, for a total of $2^{17}=131072$ possibilities.